# 1 hour of battery life lost in 10 seconds

Tags: 13.04, power-management, battery

Whenever I plug my charger out, the lifespan of my battery suddenly drops from 90 minutes to 30. By "suddenly" I mean it literally takes it around 10-15 seconds at most to drop. My battery isn't new, but it isn't broken either (lasted 2-2.5 hours unplugged on Windows 8. Not much, I know, but it's not 30 minutes either)

I've been searching for answers for quite a while now (even the "possible answers" list had quite a few similar topics) but I did not seem to find a helpful answer. Maybe it's because I'm bad at searching, maybe it's because I'm still slightly freaking out.

Either way, your guidance would be very helpful.

Using 13.04, 64-bit.

PS.: I have Jupiter and Intel Graphic Drivers for Linux installed already.

PSS: upower dump :

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon Oct  7 19:33:49 2013 (497 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               Sanyo
  model:                DELL 4YRJH13
  serial:               7732
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon Oct  7 19:33:55 2013 (491 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    energy:              48.6 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         48.6 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0108 W
    voltage:             12.343 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            56.2444%
    technology:          lithium-ion

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.20
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   no
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter)

Comment: @Stan You can use `powertop` to see what is draining your battery power. Also providing your machine specs (CPU, Optimus/hybrid GPU technology?, etc) should help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Stan: The possible reason might me your graphics card driver. It is possible that no graphics driver installed for your laptop, all burden goes to processor and it consumes a lot of power. Same happened to me with HP Pavilion laptop with AMD Radeon graphics cards. After installing graphics driver my problem solved. I suggest you to post some more info about your `laptop and graphics cards`

Comment: Run `upower --dump` and add the output to your question.